# ASUS USB-N13 Wireless Adaptor Losing connection

Tags: wireless, asus

I have just purchased a new ASUS USB-N13 as it was recommended for use with Ubuntu 14.04. MY connection is set up but closes around every 10 minutes, it then asks my for my Wi-Fi
password again to log on "it gets a bit frustrating after 10 times". Anyone else had this problem or know a fix for it??

Comment: What WiFi chip does the ASUS USB-N13 use? If you don't know, you can open a Terminal, and type `lsusb`, then press Enter. One of the devices should be your ASUS USB-N13, and the line should look something like `Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:0737 Microsoft Corp. Compact Optical Mouse 500` (my example is for a mouse, but yours should be similar).

Comment: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:17ab ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N13 802.11n Network Adapter (rev. B1) [Realtek RTL8192CU]

Comment: Any ideas what I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you go to Asus' support site, locate your device, and click the OS dropdown and select Linux you can find the driver that purportedly supports your device. [Device Support Page](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=USB-N13&os=30)

Also, not sure how much help this may be but here's a forum thread on getting your device working with Ubuntu. [Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1419504) In the thread they claim the 2010 driver *may* be defective, so, there's that.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest driver from the site and installed it. But i am still having the same problem. I lose connection then get asked for my password again! Been trying for a week now without getting anywhere. I'm trying my best to sort it as i do not want to revert back to Windows.

Comment: What kind of network is this you're connecting to? Home network? Just password? Or is it enterprise 802.1x with username and password? I have run into your problem with the latter network type without ever using your wireless dongle.

Comment: Just a home network. It's connecting at 72mb the drops to 7mb goes off then asks for my password then connects again!

Comment: Well, I am not finding anything specific to your device. However, I have some threads/answers that may bee of help. [Answer 1](http://askubuntu.com/a/418029/292342) and even simpler [Answer 2](http://askubuntu.com/a/459932/292342).

Comment: Thanks I’ll take a look. There is a few threads on here that I’ve tried but none of them have resolved the problem.

Comment: After trying every solution eg building drivers and other such fixes to no avail. I have finally given up. I've purchased a TP-AV5OO Power adaptor kit. My network is now up and running at 100Mps with no problem. Goodbye wireless network. Anyone who wants to check the power kit out here's the link      http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-PA411 Thanks for your help guys :-)

Comment: Sorry we couldn't get it working. Any time flaz :D