# Ubuntu keeps asking for Wifi password

Tags: networking, wireless, dual-boot

I've recently installed the latest version of Ubuntu (64 bit), alongside my Windows 8 dual booted machine. The problem I'm having is trying to connect to my school network, the school uses a username and password system, so upon entering them the top right corner icon attempts to connect to to the network, but after some amount of time either disconnects, or tells me to enter the details again.

On another note, my computer appears to work fine wireless wise when I'm at home (Which only requires password entry and not a username to get on the network). Also, I know this problem has nothing to do with my schools internet because I'm using it at this moment, on Windows 8.

I've tried suggestions from these links, all to no avail:

[Ubuntu 14.04 : My computer sees the wireless network, but won't connect to it, keeps asking for the WPA password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458967/ubuntu-14-04-my-computer-sees-the-wireless-network-but-wont-connect-to-it-k)

[Constantly asked for WiFi password and CA certificate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456970/constantly-asked-for-wifi-password-and-ca-certificate)

Comment: Hi, can you provide some more details? run dmesg and share it's output.

Comment: Is it something similar to this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap

Comment: I'm using the working network now (the one at home, so should I still run that command and post the output?) Or does using a working network not make a difference here.

Comment: I'll paste a paste bin tomorrow, if the fixes in the link provided don't work.

Comment: Hi again. It would be interesting if you could run dmesg while having the problem, thus while connected or connecting to school's network.

Comment: Here is the dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/kAdREsU5

Comment: 154.335905] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:c4:d1:e2:f0

[ 2154.354211] wlan0: direct probe to 00:24:c4:d1:e2:f0 (try 1/3)

[ 2154.557675] wlan0: direct probe to 00:24:c4:d1:e2:f0 (try 2/3)

[ 2154.761957] wlan0: direct probe to 00:24:c4:d1:e2:f0 (try 3/3)

[ 2154.965973] wlan0: authentication with 00:24:c4:d1:e2:f0 timed out

Comment: You can see the auth failing. I need to dig into this with some time. Can you provide details of the connection? Any type of certificate is required to access this network other than user and pass?

Comment: Just username and pass, and I`ve noticed some new behaviour after trying the suggestions from your link. If I restart the laptop,and boot into ubuntu the top right Icon tells me I'm connected.however,when I try to use the Internet, it loads extremely slowly. Also, if I disconnect and attempt to reconnect(hibernate,suspend or airplane mode) the same problem with the laptop not connecting to the network persists.

Comment: I can see the `wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:24:c4:d1:e0:c1 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)`. But this is very broad class of reasons; Can be a power saving mode issue a dhcp6 issue or a ca_cert issue (well, not your case)  `lspci | grep Net` should give your device details about the network card. You can try disabling the power saving mode and see what happens. `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off `

Comment: I'm getting an error after running that : "Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
". And sadly, I'm having the same wifi problems with my home network now (I'm absolutely stumped at the moment how a OS can be so buggy)

Comment: I had the same problem, but the root cause of the issue was on the router. Issue is fixed after changing the Encryption method to WPA(TKIP) in router (D-Link) setting.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. In case it is helpful for anyone, for me it was just a matter of changing from TLS to PEAP under the network settings.

Answer (score 0):

If your school has one password for wifi:
Click on the intenet connectivity menu (top right corner menu with wifi signal).
Click Edit connections.
Find your school's network from the list and select.
Click edit.
Click Wi-Fi Security tab.
Set securitty to WPA & WPA2 personal (assuming thats the system your school uses).
Enter your password.

If it is the kind where you log onto some service, maybe try fogetting the network and re-connecting to it
Click the internet connectivity menu.
Click edit connections.
Find your school's network from the list and select.
Click delete.
Wait a minute.
Click internet connectivity menu.
Find your school's network.
Click on it and see if things start working.

Comment: Our school login is based on each student, so everyone password and username our different. And as for your second suggestion, I've tried that already :(

Comment: Bummer. I got nothing then. Anyone else?

Comment: @user20842454566 This happens to me when the campus network here is over saturated and the access point fails to handle all the connections (and we have individual student logins via 802.11x) - is it possible that's what's going on?  (Usually clears up for me within 30 minutes)

Comment: Don't think so because my home wifi is having this problem as well now. And hey the school wifi  works fine on windows.